# Simplify nested lapplys

Tags: r

I want to map a list to a list of lists and do a function. Currently I have nested lapplys, but I just don't like it and want to do this in one mapping, if it's possible. I've created a simplified version of my code where I paste the year and day together. Really my function is raster() and I'm creating a list of list of raster objects by year and then by day. Thanks for any help, or pointing me to any previous posts I missed!

Example reproducible code I want to simplify-

```
exmp1 <- list(list(4, 7,9), list(23, 28), list(5, 32, 82, 99))
exmp2 <- list(1999, 2000, 2001)

exmp3 <- seq(from = 1, to = length(exmp1))
foo <- lapply(exmp3, function(w) { 
  lapply(exmp1[[w]], function(k){
    paste(exmp2[[w]], k)
    })})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use `Map` here :

```
Map(paste, exmp1, exmp2)
```

For more complicated function you can use an anonymous function to include more lines of code.

```
Map(function(x, y) paste(x, y), exmp1, exmp2)
```

Comment: I believe OP needs `Map(function(...) as.list(paste(...)), exmp2, exmp1)`.

Comment: This worked for my simplified example, but not working for the function I actually care about, ```foo <- Map(function(x, y) raster(x, layer = y), r, days)``` I end up with just a list of three raster objects, instead of a list of lists

Comment: in the raster() function, because y has a length greater than one, only the first element is evaluated, instead of evaluating x and each value of y.

Comment: Yes, you can do `Map(function(x, y) lapply(y, function(p) raster(x, p)), exmp1, exmp2)` but this is no different than your nested `lapply`.

Comment: This is still better than my first solution, so I'm gonna call it good.